# Tagging python tests for selective execution

Tags: automated-testing, python

What I am trying to do is :
create a tagging system for around 400 tests so I can run them selectively.
For example, some tags may be UI_elements, production, staging etc.
When a developer makes a change that affects a feature that I have a tag associated with, I want to run only those tests specifically.

I am currently trying to make pytest's tagging system to work but to no avail.
http://pytest.org/latest/example/markers.html

I am using pytest 2.3.5 and it is difficult to upgrade it (if that is the case).
I do exactly what the guide says but Pycharm does not recognize the `.mark.` bit.
What am I doing wrong??

UPDATE:
I updated pytest to it's latest version (pytest-2.6.4) but the problem remains.

Comment: Might not be an answer to your question, therefore as comment. Phyton 2.6 and later supports xunit through the pyunit module, and pyunit supports creating testsuites. So replace the tagging the test by adding the test to the respective testsuite

Comment: Is this question really about getting markers to work in pytest or about how to upgrade pytest?

Comment: I know how to upgrade pytest. I just dont want to, if it will be needed in order for the tagging to work, because there are other things depending on the pytest's version.